# Do I have to downcast or am I missing something?

Tags: swift, swiftui

So I have a Type that I would like to make dynamic at the call site:

```
    struct DynamicView<Content: View>: View {
    let content: Content
    var body: some View {
              content
           }
    }
```

using some type of function that would convert it into something concrete

```
    static func contentCreator<T: View>(id: Int) -> T {
    switch id {
    case 0:
        return FirstView() //<-- Xcode is demanding that I state as! T here
    }
}
```

where FirstView

```
struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
    }
}
```

Am I approaching this wrong or what? As long as they all conform to a common protocol, they should be interchangeable right?

Comment: You are not using T in contentCreator, so do you really need it? Maybe the function should return `some View`?

Comment: Well I am using it, just as a constraint of what my return type should be, but not directly you're right

Comment: Not clear how `contentCreator` linked to `DynamicView`. BTW, generics is actually input parametrisation, not output.

Comment: @Asperi Initially I wanted to use `DynamicView` well, dynamically, in place of `FirstView` inside of the switch statement, but ran into a similar problem

Comment: @JoakimDanielson True, really this should be a @ViewBuilder but that is only good for `View` . I am still curious as to go about this for custom Protocols

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's because the type is not inferred by checking return.

If you try:

```
let v = contentCreator(id: 0)
```

You will get a `Generic parameter T could not be inferred` error, because v type is unknown.

If type is set, it will compile :

```
let v: View = contentCreator(id: 0)
```

So to get back to you interrogation, since View is a protocol, when Xcode builds the source, it has no way to know the class 'T', and no way to force you to use the right type when you use it.

```
struct FirstView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Circle()
    }
}

struct SecondView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Square()
    }
}

// This will work, because once executed, we know v1 class. 
// The cast will work as long as v1 is declared as conforming to 'View' protocol. 
// Type is not inferred in this case, but known only when it returns.

let v1: View = contentCreator(0)

/// This won't work, because the inferred type is 'SecondView'. 
/// The cast 'return FirstView() as! T' will crash

let v2: SecondView = contentCreator(0)
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume you just looking for something like this

```
@ViewBuilder
func contentCreator(id: Int) -> some View {
    switch id {
        case 0:
            FirstView()
        case 1:
            SecondView()
        // ...
        default:
            EmptyView()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats a good fix when the protocol is View but was looking to understand this concept more generically